# Without using each loop in jquery how can rotate the values

Tags: jquery

[image]

In student marks list where i changed marks1 automatically total and average will change 
i used a code like this in jquery

```
$("#total_" + this.name)[0].innerHTML = parseFloat($("#marks1_" + this.name).val()) + parseFloat($("#marks2_" + this.name).val()) + parseFloat($("#marks3_" + this.name).val());
$("#average_" + this.name)[0].innerHTML = (((parseFloat($("#marks1_" + this.name).val()) + parseFloat($("#marks2_" + this.name).val()) + parseFloat($("#marks3_" + this.name).val())) / 300) * 100).toFixed(2);
```

like this how to change automatically  grand total without using each loop
i used the grand total like this

```
$("#grandtotal")[0].innerHTML += parseFloat($("#marks1_" + this.name).val()) + parseFloat($("#marks2_" + this.name).val()) + parseFloat($("#marks3_" + this.name).val());
```

Comment: If you're going to place some strange restriction (without loop) it might be useful to explain why.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before settings new student total value, obtain the old value:

```
var oldStudentTotal = parseFloat($("#total_" + this.name).html());
var newStudentTotal = parseFloat($("#marks1_" + this.name).val()) + 
  parseFloat($("#marks2_" + this.name).val()) + 
  parseFloat($("#marks3_" + this.name).val());

$("#total_" + this.name).html(newStudentTotal);
```

Then, subtract the old student total value from old grand total and add new student total value:

```
var oldGrandTotal = parseFloat($("#grandtotal").html());
var newGrandTotal = oldGrandTotal - oldStudentTotal + newStudentTotal;

$("#grandtotal").html(newGrandTotal);
```

Do the same for average values.

Comment: in grand total its not getting any value

Comment: what are `oldStudentTotal`, `newStudentTotal`, `oldGrandTotal`, `newGrandTotal` values?

Comment: oldstudenttotal =144 (qaz) newstudenttotal=222 oldgrndtotal=1748 and then not getting newgrandtotal values

Comment: what is "144 (qaz)"? are you trying to `parseFloat` a string that is not a number?

Comment: That means i am telling that last column i changed the value

Comment: I don't understand your last sentence.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion to the rescue!

```js
function rowRec($currentRow) {
  if ($currentRow.length == 0)
    return 0;

  var rowTotal = cellRec($currentRow.find(".mark").first());

  $currentRow.find(".total").text(rowTotal);
  $currentRow.find(".average").text(rowTotal / $currentRow.find(".mark").length);

  return rowTotal + rowRec($currentRow.next(".resultsRow"));
}

function cellRec($currentCell) {
  if ($currentCell.length == 0)
    return 0;
  var thisCellValue = parseFloat($currentCell.text());

  return thisCellValue + cellRec($currentCell.next(".mark"));
}

var grandTotal = rowRec($("tr.resultsRow").first());
var grandAvg = grandTotal / ($(".mark").length);
$(".grand_total").text(grandTotal);
$(".grand_average").text(grandAvg);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Mark1</th>
      <th>Mark2</th>
      <th>Mark3</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Average</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="resultsRow">
      <td class="name">Name 1</td>
      <td class="age">14</td>
      <td class="mark">75</td>
      <td class="mark">77</td>
      <td class="mark">84</td>
      <td class="total"></td>
      <td class="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="resultsRow">
      <td class="name">Name 2</td>
      <td class="age">17</td>
      <td class="mark">43</td>
      <td class="mark">56</td>
      <td class="mark">32</td>
      <td class="total"></td>
      <td class="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="resultsRow">
      <td class="name">Name 3</td>
      <td class="age">16</td>
      <td class="mark">87</td>
      <td class="mark">99</td>
      <td class="mark">75</td>
      <td class="total"></td>
      <td class="average"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="resultsRow">
      <td class="name">Name 4</td>
      <td class="age">15</td>
      <td class="mark">54</td>
      <td class="mark">67</td>
      <td class="mark">23</td>
      <td class="total"></td>
      <td class="average"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td class="grand_total"></td>
      <td class="grand_average"></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: shhh, don't look at where it says `next()`